# How come the same variable can be used for 3 different things?

Tags: java, android, class, properties

I am following a tutorial on Udacity and there's something I don't understand. Below is a custom class adapter:

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = WordAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    public WordAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Word> Word) {
        super(context, 0, Word);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        // Get the {@link AndroidFlavor} object located at this position in the list
        Word currentWord = getItem(position);

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_name
        TextView defaultTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_one);
        // Get the version name from the current AndroidFlavor object and
        // set this text on the name TextView
        defaultTextView.setText(currentWord.getDefaultTranslation());

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_number
        TextView miwokTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_lutti);
        // Get the version number from the current AndroidFlavor object and
        // set this text on the number TextView
        miwokTextView.setText(currentWord.getMiwokTranslation());

        ImageView numberImageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_id);
        numberImageView.setImageResource(currentWord.getImageResourceID());


        // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews)
        // so that it can be shown in the ListView
        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

We declared a variable named `currentWord` whose data type is `Word` (a custom class), then we used this variable in 2 `TextView`s and 1 `ImageView`, where we used it to get words. The part I don't understand is how can we use a single variable that equals to single value (`getitem(position)`) in 3 ways and not one?

Comment: The text views and image views are not using the Word directly. The Word first gets a method called, like `currentWord.getMiwokTranslation()`, which then returns a value to the `setText()`. The methods do not have to return a Word, they can return anything.

Comment: What to you think `getDefaultTranslation()`, `getMiwokTranslation()`, and `getImageResourceID()` does? Since `Word` is a custom class, look at the source code.

Comment: here's a start: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Comment: @JosephYoung ah, so you mean since there's no return value for currentWord therefor it can be used in another way?

Comment: It can't. It has members and methods. Next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`currentWord` references an **object**, which means it can have various `public` methods and properties that the user can access (look at the source code of the class if it's available to you).

It's not that "the same variable" is used for different things, because each of the following has potentially a different value:

- `currentWord.getDefaultTranslation()` (for example, this could return `"Dog"`).
- `currentWord.getMiwokTranslation()` (for example, this could return `"Chuku"`).
- `currentWord.getImageResourceID()` (for example, this could return `327984579294`).

Which means that a different "variable" is accessed each time, and `currentWord` is used to store this collection of variables.

You might want to read about *Encapsulation*.

Comment: @hellohello If this answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Take a look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) for an explanation of why it is important.